# Changing .show() to a variable to save with local Storage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a level based game. So when the player hits the top of the level it will `.show()` The next level's button.

I need it to save that with HTML localStorage, but first things first I need to convert it to a string/array type so I can store it easily.

I've tried this method right here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var levelsSaved = 1;
    $('#button2').hide();
    $('#button1').click(function() {
        levelsSaved = [1, 2];
    });
    if (levelsSaved == 2) {
        $('#button2').show();
    }
});
```

However, when you click Level one button nothing happens, I don't get any errors or console messages. So I honestly do not know what's going on.

Here is a link to my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1dvjqf15/1/

Comment: An array (eg `[1,2]`) can't be equal to a number (eg `2`)

Comment: [Is this what you're after?](http://jsfiddle.net/e6L16556/)

Comment: your above code will be executed on page load, if the user then clicks the first button you create an array and nothing more happens. You need to implement some way to activate a button as soon as the level value changes.

Comment: @NicholasAyoub It's not just `.length`, but also making sure that code doesn't run until the button is clicked

Comment: ooh thank's for that little explination. Also really quick shouldn't this work,                                                            '    localStorage.savedLevels = JSON.stringify(levelsSaved);' , When I go to my console and check Local Storage it only saved 1 level but really I clicked and unlocked level two?

Comment: why do you even need an array and not just the value of highest level?

Comment: @NicholasAyoub That would depend on when `localStorage` was updated. Was that code in your comment executed _after_ `levelsSaved` was changed?

Answer (score 0):

You should move the login inside the event handler - http://jsfiddle.net/sahilbatla/1dvjqf15/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var levelsSaved = 1;
    $('#button2').hide();
    $('#button1').click(function() {
        levelsSaved = [1,2];
        if(levelsSaved.length == 2) {
            $('#button2').show();
        }        
    });
});
```

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't what OP wants. That `if` statement is pointless in this code because it will always be true.

Comment: true, I don't see the use of it myself, but his comment above suggests that he wants to check the levels, probably all the levels that are being covered.